# Android Studio not able to update Indices

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

This Background task "Updating Indices, Building symbols" keeps running for hours and I am unable to see work on my code. 
I tried clearing cache on my Mac library for studio,
Installing a newer version of Android Studio Code, to no use. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Is gradle build finished ?

Comment: No, doesn't reach till there

Comment: May be that url is blocked in network so try to open url from browser.

Comment: How can I find that URL in android studio ?

Comment: did you tried this Invalidate Caches / Restart option?

Comment: @moosa0709 all those menu options are disabled , can't access any except for Android Studio menu option. Every time I am force quitting Android Studio so that build process could start again and I could find some log in background task to give an hint to solve it

Comment: Not sure what was causing it, but I deleted All the folders containing reference to AndroidStudio (Like library-> cache-> AndroidStudio, Library-> ApplicationSupport -> Android Studio and everywhere else inside library folder + .Android folder), I reinstalled whole studio, with fresh checkout of SDK  and now I am not getting the issue. There were few references to my old AndroidStudio2.3 in ApplicationSupport, which I deleted. My best guess is some property from that old studio was causing this issue. Still Waiting for correct answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Change your 'Android SDK Location' path it will work.
I have the same issue and I have fixed this after change SDK path.

Go to Settings-> Appearance & Behavior ->  System Settings -> Android Sdk -> change this path 'Android SDK Location'